# Save file to folder

Tags: javascript

I am using jspdf to generate PDf file. When I use save function, it saves / download the file to 'Download' folder. Instead of that, I would like to save file to a specific folder automatically through JavaScript

Comment: show me the cold where you are saving it

Comment: Javascript has no access to client file system, the browser itself and its configuration is what choose the path to save files too.

Comment: you don't have control of that.

Comment: This needs more information. Are you trying to do this in a browser? With node?

Comment: ^ needs more info, and could you explain why you need to do this? Is it a personal project/challenge, or is it for work (your boss asked you to do this)? If it's the latter, explain to him/her that it's just not possible (for security issues) - if they beg to differ, please have them share where they seen this happen.

Comment: there's no way to control that via JS, but it is typically a user-configurable browser option.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're talking about doing this in the browser, you can't do this.  The user chooses where the file is saved.  If your browser is saving it do the Downloads folder without asking you where it should be downloaded to, that's because that's the default setting for your browser.

If you're using javascript in some offline capacity, as a local script, the answer could be different.  We won't know unless you provide some of your code.